# how do I pull a specific div from a ebsite using PHP & cURL?

Tags: php, regex, curl

This is the code i have so far

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://www.tesco.com/store-locator/uk/?bID=2136');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) 
{
echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<div itemtype="case_textlist">(.*?)<\/div>/s'; <-- confused with this
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
echo $list[0];
else
print "Not found";
?>
```

I want to get the information from the divs that contain opening times on the URL I have at the start of my code, however i don't understand what I have to put in the $regex part to get the opening times.

just another quick question, i tried to do this for another website but i just get this error: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in H:\xampp\htdocs\dsa\php2.php on line 16
any ideas?

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://www.masterofmalt.com/contact-us/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) 
{
echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

preg_match('/<span itemprop="name">(.*)<\/span>/iU', $page, $list);
echo $list[0];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do.  Find everything between the divs surrounding the hours box.  Use the "U" pattern modifier to have it be "Ungreedy" and stop after it finds the first closing div tag.

```
preg_match('/<div class="fb hours">(.*)<\/div>/iU', $page, $list);
```

Then, in the '$list' variable, use $1 to store everything that it matched.

```
$list[1];
```

Now that you've got the entire block of times, search through that using 'preg_match_all' and pull out each of the times and put them into an array called '$opening_times'.

```
preg_match_all('/<td colspan="2">(.*)<\/td>/iU', $list[1], $opening_times);
```

Using the $1 to pull out everything between the tds, we now have an array of the times.

```
$opening_times_array = $opening_times[1];
```

Comment: ok I got this working however i still have no clue on how you got this bit: '/<div class="fb hours">(.*)<\/div>/iU'

Comment: I just viewed the source code of the page that you listed in your question and found in that code the div that contained the opening hours.

Comment: oh ok, so does (.*) mean between the class "fb hours and the next div to be closed?

Comment: Yes, dot '.' means any character and asterisk '*' means zero or more times.  (So basically saying match ANYTHING it finds until it hits the closing div tag.)  You'll want to make sure you use the Ungreedy 'U' pattern modifier so that it stops once it hits the first '</div>'; Otherwise it will keep on going.

Comment: NEVER USE THE U MODIFIER! It is completely unnecessary and only serves to confuse. Whenever you need to use a non-greedy (lazy) quantifier on a token, add it directly to the quantifier itself in the pattern in the form of an appended question mark. i.e. `/(.*?)/` is equivalent to `/(.*)/U`. I very rarely give answers a thumbs down, but in this case, when you actually recommend using a bad practice, this answer gets my -1. Also, you do realize that when you use the `U` modifier, it not only makes greedy quantifiers lazy, it also makes lazy quantifiers greedy.